# Committee Probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the answers to these questions:

Ten students A, B... are in a class. A committee of 3 is chosen from the class. Find the probability that

1. A belongs to the committee = 3/10
2. B belongs to the committee = 3/10
3. A and B belong to committee = 1/15
4. A or B belong to the committee = 8/15

Where is 3/10 coming from? Why wouldn't it be 1/10? Thank you !

Comment: How many committees are possible?  There are $\binom{10}{3}$ equally likely committees possible.  How many committees contain person $A$?  $\binom{9}{2}$ contain person $A$.  Taking the ratio, we have the probability that $A$ is in the committee is $\binom{9}{2}/\binom{10}{3}$.  What is this value simplified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of forming a committee under some condition $X$ is given by

$$
\frac{\text{Number of committees that favor } X}{\text{Total number of committees}}
$$

Total number of committees that can be formed from 10 students by selecting 3 students $= \binom{10}{3} = \frac{10}{3}\binom{9}{2} = \frac{10\times 9}{3\times 2}\binom{8}{1}$.

1. If $A$ must be in the committee, total number of such committees = $\binom{9}{2}$.
2. Same as the previous case, $\binom{9}{2}$.
3. If both $A$ and $B$ must be in the committee, then we have freedom only in choosing the other member. Hence, number of such committees $= \binom{8}{1}$.
4. Total number of such committees is just the sum of the number of favorable committees in the previous cases.

Answer (score 1):

The members of the class can be represented as a list of 10 items:
$$\{\underbrace{\star,\star,\star}_{\text{3 committee members}},\underbrace{\unicode{x1F6B9},\unicode{x1F6B9},\dots,\unicode{x1F6B9}}_{\text{7 non-committee members}}\}.$$
Here $\star$ and $\unicode{x1f6b9}$ stand for committee and non-committee members respectively.  Student $A$ can be placed with *equal probability* into one of the above 10 places.  3 of them represent committee member.  That's where the answer $3/10$ from.